# Go type assertion conversion

Tags: go

I can convert an int to a float64 like this:

```
var a int = 10
var b float64 = float64(a)
```

With regards to type assertions, Effective Go states: 'The type must either be the concrete type held by the interface, or a second interface type that the value can be converted to.'

With that in mind, why does the following fail:

```
func foo(a interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(a.(float64))
}

func main() {
    var a int = 10
    foo(a)
}
```

This causes a `panic: interface conversion: interface is int, not float64`.

Note that the Go Spec says:

'For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary expression

```
x.(T)
```

asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.'

Which does contradict the Effective Go statement but seems more in line with what I see.

Answer (score 9):

[This sentence](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions) in Effective Go seems indeed to be confusing. It looks like the author was thinking about structs at that time.

[The chapter on assertions in the specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) is much clearer :

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression
>
> x.(T) asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of
>   type T. The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.
>
> More precisely, if T is not an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the
>   dynamic type of x is identical to the type T. In this case, T must
>   implement the (interface) type of x; otherwise the type assertion is
>   invalid since it is not possible for x to store a value of type T. If
>   T is an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x
>   implements the interface T.

The fact [you can convert your int to a float](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) (and the reverse) doesn't at all mean you can assert they're the same type.

Comment: agreed, however as suggested by the run-time panic message, the operation is actually an 'interface conversion', as opposed to an assertion.  It would be nice if this sort of conversion could happen naturally.

Comment: You can do a type switch. What more natural do you have in mind ?

Comment: @Ferguzz: Go is pretty explicit in all its conversions, there are _no_ implicit or automatic conversions. This is a very good thing. Kinds of "natural conversions" are the complete opposite to explicit.

Comment: Say I want to convert any numeric type to a float64, this would be the only way?

http://play.golang.org/p/hQ5cOowDNt

Comment: There might be "simpler" solution with bit play (or small hacks) but if you need this, you might have a design problem somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

> The type must either be the concrete type held by the interface, or a second **interface** type that the value can be converted to

This basically explains the [following](http://play.golang.org/p/7dbXeMxFR3):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Stringer interface {
    String()
}

type Byter interface {
    Bytes()
}

type Stringbyter interface {
    Stringer
    Byter
}

type Polymorphic float64

func (p *Polymorphic) String() {}

func (p *Polymorphic) Bytes() {}

func main() {
    i := interface{}(new(Polymorphic))
    if _, ok := i.(Stringer); ok {
        fmt.Println("i can be asserted to Stringer")
    }
    if _, ok := i.(Byter); ok {
        fmt.Println("i can be asserted to Byter")
    }
    if _, ok := i.(Stringbyter); ok {
        fmt.Println("i can be asserted to Stringbyter")
    }
    if _, ok := i.(*Polymorphic); ok {
        fmt.Println("i can be asserted to *Polymorphic")
    }
    if _, ok := i.(int); ok {
        fmt.Println("i can be asserted to int") // Never runs
    }
}
```

The assertion to `int` fails because it's a **concrete** type (as opposed to interface type) which is not `*Polymorphic` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can only type assert from interface type to underlying type. In this case `int`. Then you use type conversion from `int` to `float64`